# complement of {a^lb^mc^n:n>l+m}

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

If we have this language $ L = \{a^mb^nc^n:m,n \in N\}$, would its complement be $\{a,b,c\}^* \setminus L = L^\complement = \{c^nb^na^m:m,n \in N\}$? This was the professor's answer, which I find incorrect, because it doesn't include for example $aba$, which should be in the complement as well. Since the given language is not regular, we can't construct a DFA to get a compliment, but this intuitive solution from professor is not understood by me at least, can you help explain why?

Comment: Seems like your professor made a mistake, and you found it!

Comment: :) thanks, how would you give the complement of that?